# nsupdate in basic CSH script for BIND in unix

Tags: unix, dns, bind, freebsd, csh

I have never used C and I'm not writing this for security reasons, i am just writing this script to test an update via nsupdate to my BIND for a specific zone being "zoneA.unix". But i am receiving "option: undefined variable"  
 And I'm not to sure if this is the correct way to do nsupdate via a user's inputs.

```
echo "First of all we need to grab your username:"
set uname = $<
 if ($uname == "zoneA")then
 echo "password: "
 set passwd = $<
    if ($passwd == "Azone")then
            echo "you are in"
            echo "now to do the nsupdate"
            echo "do you wish to (A)dd or (D)elete a record"
            set numeric = $<
                    if ($numeric == "A")then
                    $option = "add"
                    $testinga = "add"
                    else if($numeric == "D")then
                    $option = "delete"
                    $testinga = "delete"
                    endif
            echo "what to $testinga to the zone zoneA.unix?"
            set innerzonename = $<
            nsupdate -k /usr/local/etc/namedb/Keys/Kzonea.+157+57916.key -v
            debug yes
            zone zonea.unix
            update $testinga $innerzonename 86400 A 127.0.0.1
            show
            echo "is this correct (Y)es (n)"
            set sendoff = $<
  if($sendoff == "Y")then
  send
  else if ($sendoff == "N")then
  quit
  endif
```

So the code works fine til the $option part and I'm not to sure if it will work after the input needed during the nsupdate because it won't pause it, well i don't know how i can pause it.
 What it seems to be doing is running nsupdate and waiting until nsupdate is finished. anyway i can pass them into it?

Comment: not sure what your code `$option = "add"`, and numerous similar statements are supposed to be doing. Either `"$option" == "add"` or `set option = "add"` would be the 2 likely corrections You have used those two forms already, so why not now? Good luck.

Comment: Also, the `debug yes  zone ...` etc. below nsupdate looks suspicious. Do you mean to be feeding those cmds/terms into nsupdate as inputs?  That won't work. If your lucky, `HERE` files (using `<<EOS`) may work. Go thru the csh section at http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html to get up to speed (and see why you shouldn't spend too much time with `csh`). Good luck.

Comment: Hello, yes I'm thinking about running just a small php server to push the total nsupdate into a text file and then running nsupdate -v textfile.txt

But i have updated it I'm now echoing all the nsupdate commands to a text file and running nsupdate -v. i will add the answer to my own question if i am allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Way all i am doing is pushing the nsupdate's to a text file and reading it from the text file using nsupdate -v textile. seems to be working like a charm at the moment

```
if ($uname == "zoneA")then
echo "password: "
set passwd = $<
    if ($passwd == "Azone")then
            echo "you are in"
            echo "now to do the nsupdate"
            echo "do you wish to add or delete a record"
            set numeric = $<
            echo "what to $numeric to the zone zoneA.unix?"
            set innerzonename = $<
            //nsupdate -k /usr/local/etc/namedb/Keys/Kzonea.+157+57916.key
            echo "server "localhost"">>textfiles/stillneedanewname
            echo "debug yes" >> textfiles/stillneedanewname
            echo "zone zonea.unix" >> textfiles/stillneedanewname
            echo "update $numeric $innerzonename.zonea.unix. 86400 A 136.186.230.90" >> textfiles/stillneedanewname
            echo "show" >> textfiles/stillneedanewname
            echo "send" >> textfiles/stillneedanewname
            nsupdate -k /usr/local/etc/namedb/Keys/Kzonea.+157+57916.key -v textfiles/stillneedanewname
```

Comment: looks good. You can accept your own answer after 48 hrs (I think, maybe less), and gain more reputation points. Glad you got a working solution. Good luck.

Comment: Yea, was a little difficult but this way i can modify a few things, just creating a script to run on par with updating the reverse lookup zones as well,
but thank you i will continue working on it.